# SQL Server configuring both UCP and MDW on a single server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, configuration, management-data-warehouse

I'm trying to configure both UCP and MDW on a SQL Server.

I have already setup UCP and it created [sysutility_mdw] database.

Now when i try to setup MDW it is trying to use sysutility_mdw database created in #1

Should I use same database for both UCP and MDW or should I create separate ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the same database for UCP and MDW.

Actually, you can't use a different database. UCP is in fact a specialized collection set that uploads its data to a MDW database. The MDW database is unique for a SQL Server instance and Data Collector cannot upload different collection sets to different MDW databases.

The database name for UCP *must* be "sysutility_mdw" and cannot be changed, so if you decide to activate UCP, you will have to stick to that name. That's why I always advise naming the MDW database "sysutility_mdw", so you can activate UCP in the future. To be fair, very few people use it.

Comment: Thanks! I have found a interesting thing. When I first create UCP and then go for MDW, it suggests to use same DB created for UCP. But If I do other way around, it doesn't suggest this.